# Selenium Set Attribute is not working when trying to execute the script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get set the date filter value on the webpage https://www.icc-cricket.com/rankings/mens/player-rankings/odi/batting but I'm not able to do so. I have tried setting the value of the attribute but not getting the final result. The element is as shown below:

```
<div class="drop-down__current js-drop-down-current" data-value="2022">  2022 </div>
```

Here, I want to change the value of 'data-value' to my desired year. The code that I have been using is as given below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
import datetime
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
date_list = pd.date_range(start = "2022-02-01", end=datetime.date.today(), freq='1d')
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = 'https://www.icc-cricket.com/rankings/mens/player-rankings/odi'
driver.get(url)
l = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", l)

for date in date_list:
    year = date.year
    month = date.month
    day = date.day
    drop1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]")
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", drop1)
    driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('data-option',{year})",drop1)
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]").text)
```

And the output is

```
Please select
Please select
Please select
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Look into this element <ul class="drop-down__dropdown-list js-drop-down-options">. First click the dropdown then click a li tag in this element.

Comment: Maybe driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('data-value',{year})",drop1)

Comment: @YuMa that doesn't work.